# Django can not makemigrations: can't create form field for followers yet. Because its related model 'self' has not been loaded yet

Tags: django, django-models

This is the model.

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    followers = ArrayField(ArrayField(models.ForeignKey('self',
                                                        related_name = 'following_set',
                                                        on_delete = models.CASCADE ), size = 1))
    followings = ArrayField(ArrayField(models.ForeignKey('self',
                                                        related_name = 'follower_set',
                                                        on_delete = models.CASCADE ), size = 1))
```

Comment: Please do *not* use an `ArrayField`, you should use a m2m relation (or add a table in between). In fact arrays are not good practice anyway (these do not follow 1NF).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the documentation on an [**`ArrayField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield) says, you can not use a [**`ForeignKey`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey):

> **`base_field`**
>
> This is a required argument.
>
> Specifies the underlying data type and behavior for the array. It
>   should be an instance of a subclass of `Field`. For example, it could
>   be an `IntegerField` or a `CharField`. Most field types are permitted,
>   with the **exception of those handling relational data**
>   (**`ForeignKey`**, **`OneToOneField`** and **`ManyToManyField`**).

Furthermore `ArrayField`s are usually *not* good practice anyway. A lot of database backends do *not* support these fields, and furthermore they easily result in complex queries, and frequently there are no efficient indexing structures on these anyway: if you want to find out what the common followers are of two users, that will result in some complicated logic. If you have to query inside the array, then it definitely does not follow the conditions of the [first normal form (1NF) [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) of databases. Although of course one can debate if 1NF always improves the overall quality of a database, I think it is defintely an extra argument to say that `ArrayField`s should usually be used as a "last resort", or if the array is an "atomical" object.

Finally by using two arrays, it will be a technical challenge to keep the two in sync: if `a` is no longer following `b`, then `a` should be removed from the `followers` of `b`, but `b` should also be removed from the `followings` of `a`. This may look easy, but eventually the number of use cases will grow, and eventually it will result in some bugs.

You can construct a [**`ManyToMany`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField), like:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    followers = models.ManyToManyField(
        'self',
        symmetrical=False,
        related_name='following'
    )
```

This will create a hidden table in between. By specifying [**`symmetrical=False`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical) this means that if a user `u1` is following a user `u2`, then `u2` is *not* per se following `u1`.

If you want to add extra data in a "following" relation, like the timestamp when a user started following another user, you can make a model like `Follow`, and specify this as the [**`through=`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) model of your `followers`.

Comment: "one can debate if 1NF always improves the overall quality of a database" are you talking about denormalization in reporting tables here..?

Comment: @thebjorn: well there can be certain situations, like databases with gigantic load, where not following 1NF might be beneficial (like sharding). So as with most design principles, there can be certain situations. I'm only saying that for non-edge cases, typically it is better to follow normal forms.

Comment: Ok, I understand (I'd just never heard of normal forms below 4 or 5 being controversial for relational data -- then again I suppose followers is as much hierarchical as relational..)